# signal strength in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, signals, carrier

im developing an ipad app where the user has to sync with the online system and download data to ipad. Now if the signal is week , i need to prompt a alert to user.

How to find if signal strength is weak or good? Apple doesnt provide any API to find the same. 
But there is an undocumented framework CoreTelephony.

In this there is a method getSignalStrength() which gives carrier strength.  i tried in ipad and it gave 46 for 3G and 0 for wi-fi as carrier strength.

Whats the minimum and maximum stregth of signal?  How to find the same for wifi.

Comment: I need method get signal strength ios 8.3 , help help